# css issue in navigation bar windows 8 metro app

Tags: css, html, windows-8

We have placed images in navigation bar in HTML page using css when the mouse is on the image it is moving from left to right. How to stop that moving animation? It should be constant.

This is css code:

```
.homebtn1 .win-commandimage {
background-image: url('/images/homeActive.png');      
width:140px;
height:75px;

.mydealsbtn1.win-commandimage {
background-image: url('/images/home2Active.png');     
width:140px;
height:75px;
```

this is html code

```
<button class="homebtn1" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="     {id:'home',section:'selection',tooltip:'Home',extraClass:'appbarExtraClass'}">
</button>
<button class="mydealsbtn1" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'mydeals',section:'selection',tooltip:'Mydeals',extraClass:'appbarExtraClass'}">
 </button>
```

This is first screen shot when mouse is on image it changes position, you can check the difference in next image.
It changes the position again from the exact position when mouse is not on the image. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Those images are moving when move is over there,their positions r changing.

Answer (score 0):

It may be moving because of transition property in any selector. Try adding `transition:none;` to above class.